# Deprecation warnings after switching to Realm 88.2

Tags: android, realm

After upgrading Realm to the newest (plugin) version that includes support for custom methods, I noticed build warnings that appear in all `RealmProxy` classes generated by Realm.

There are two same warnings about the use of getTable() in `createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject` and `copyOrUpdate` methods:

```
Warning:(328, 32) [deprecation] getTable(Class<? extends RealmObject>) in Realm has been deprecated
```

Did anyone have noticed such thing before? Is that a Realm bug? How to prevent it? (Turning off deprecation warnings is not an option for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method was the part of the old migration API. You can use now `Realm.getSchema()` or `DynamicRealm.getSchema()` instead.

See more info in the migration section: [Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)

Comment: I do not use `getTable()` anywhere explicitly, it's just part of `<my model name>RealmProxy` class that is generated automatically by Realm plugin.

Comment: I see. I think it is temporarily and will be fix in next version. And it looks that until this for avoiding this warning you have to use only old version or write a fix on your own.

Comment: I'll just wait then. Thanks!

Comment: So how should we adjust our code ?
getSchema returns schema and not Table. API is different, methods are different.